# I want to add a form for my clients to fill but I'm only able to use css in my website

Tags: html, css

I'm editing my website in Ecwid but all I'm able to edit it's its css code, I really need to insert this code:

```
<a href="Mailto:contact@bws.mx?Subject=Thank you for contacting us! Please write your question below.%0d"</a>
```

Any idea what could I do?

Comment: If you can't even add a piece of text with a link to the platform, I'd pick a new platform for your website.

Comment: I would love to, but It's the one they liked at my job, I can't change it

Answer (score 0):

Vitaly from Ecwid team here.

Ecwid is a cloud-based Ajax shopping cart, so the source files of the storefront can't be modified.

However, it is possible to add custom HTML code inside of the Ecwid storefront in a couple of ways depending on where you need this done.

**How to add a custom HTML to a specific page in Ecwid storefront**

Create a JavaScript code that will add this HTML to a specific place in the Ecwid storefront.

This code will need to detect what page is currently opened in Ecwid. For this, I suggest you subscribe to *OnPageLoaded event* in [Ecwid JS API](https://developers.ecwid.com/api-documentation#ecwid-onpageload-ecwid-onpageloaded).

Once you detect the page type you need, use the JavaScript code to insert the HTML into the DOM dynamically.

For example:

```
Ecwid.OnPageLoaded.add(function(page) {
    if (page.type == "CART") {
      // do something ...
    }
});
```

---

Now, let's see the different options you have to embed that JavaScript code:

**Ecwid is added via integration code to a single website**

For this case, you can just paste that JavaScript code into the source code of a page where Ecwid storefront is added. Make sure to add the code below the Ecwid integration code.

**Anywhere the storefront is loaded (Facebook, website, Ecwid starter site, etc.)**

For this case you should [register an application](https://developers.ecwid.com/register) for your Ecwid store and allow it access to [append external JS and/or CSS files via a link](https://developers.ecwid.com/api-documentation#add-custom-javascript-code).

Once the app is registered, let us know the URL to your script and it will be loaded and executed any time the storefront is loaded on a page.

If you have questions, please let me know here or contact us: https://developers.ecwid.com/contact

Comment: Thank you for answering! But I'm using the starter site, can I add that script there too? If so, were?

Comment: Hi @AlexTCGPro it's also possible for the Starter Sites! Please see the 'Anywhere the storefront is loaded (Facebook, website, Ecwid starter site, etc.)' section in my response.